# Covering space homeomorphism

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

In the course of an exercise from Hatcher's topology text, I came to the following point.

Given $p: \tilde{X} \to X$ the universal cover for $X$, and a continuous map $h: \tilde{X} \to \tilde{X}$ satisying $ph=p$, is it true that $h$ must be a homeomorphism?

The space $X$ is fairly nice - it's path connected, locally path-connected.

I was able to prove this, at least in the context of the problem I was working on, but it was long and messy. I proved surjectivity, openness, and injectivity of $h$ successively, and it was painful.

I'm wondering is the statement generally true, and if so, is there a nicer way to see it?

Thanks much.

Comment: The codomains of $h$ and $ph$ are different.

Comment: @Omar Thanks; I had typed an $h$ instead of a $p$.

Comment: This may not be true for infinte coverings but can't you use the universal property of covering maps to get $\tilde{X}$ will cover itself with degree 1. And a degree 1 covering is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "main result" about covering spaces is a necessary and suffiecnt condition for lifting maps to a covering space. The setup is as follows: Let $p : Y \to X$ be a covering map, let $Z$ be a path connected, locally path connected space, and choose $z_0 \in Z$, $y_0 \in Y$ so that $p(y_0) = f(z_0)$. Then a map $f : Z \to X$ lifts to a map $F : Z \to Y$ such that $pF=f$ and $F(z_0)=y_0$ if and only if $f_*(\pi_1(Z,z_0)) \subseteq p_*(\pi_1(Y,y_0))$. Moreover, when the lift exists it is unique.

If $Z$ is simply connected, this condition is always satisfied. So for the case $Y = Z = \tilde{X}$, with $f=p$, the theorem says that maps $h : \tilde{X}\to\tilde{X}$ such that $ph=h$ are uniquely determined by where they send a point $\tilde{x}_0 \in \tilde{X}$, and that they can send $\tilde{x}_0$ to *any* point you want in $p^{-1}(\tilde{x}_0)$. The uniqueness means that all such $h$ must be homemorphisms (and therefore deck transformations) as follows:

For any two points $a,b \in \tilde{X}$ such that $p(a)=p(b)$, call the unique $h$ such that $h(a)=b$ (and $ph=p$, of course), $h_{a,b}$. Then both $h_{a,b}\circ h_{b,a}$ and $\mathrm{id}_{\tilde{X}}$ satisfy $ph=p$ and send $a$ to itself. By uniqueness, they are equal. Similarly, $h_{b,a} \circ h_{a,b} = \mathrm{id}_{\tilde{X}}$.

**Here's a different proof:** I decided to add the proof my first instinct told me to write (I wrote the answer above instead because I felt it was more "standard"). You can summarize much of covering space theory in the following statement: given a space $X$ that has a universal cover (I mean, a connected, locally path-connected and semi-locally simply connected space), there is an equivalence of categories $\mathrm{Cov}(X) \to G-\mathrm{Sets}$ where:

1. The category $\mathrm{Cov}(X)$ has objects all covering spaces $p : Y \to X$, and morphisms from an object $p: Y \to X$ to an object $q : Z \to X$ being continuous maps $f : Y \to Z$ such that $qf = p$ (note that invertible such morphisms from $p : Y\to X$ to itself are deck transformations, but we include non-invertible morphisms too).
2. By $G$ I mean the fundamental group of $X$, and $G-\mathrm{Sets}$ is the category whose objects are sets $A$ with an [action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) of $G$  and whose morphisms are [$G$-equivariant maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivariant_map).

The equivalence is given by picking once and for all a basepoint $x_0 \in X$ and sending each covering space $p : Y \to X$ to the set $p^{-1}(x_0)$ with the action of $G = \pi_1(X,x_0)$ given by lifting loops in $X$ to paths in $Y$ and seeing where they end.

OK, now for the question: under this equivalence, the universal cover corresponds to the $G$-set $G$ with the action by (say) left translation. The question now translates to the following question: is every $G$-equivariant map $f : G \to G$ automatically an isomorphism? The answer is yes since any such map is just a right translation by $f(1)$: $f(g) = f(g \cdot 1) = g \cdot f(1)$.

Comment: Now I wish I could give another +1 for your extended answer!  Since you don't care, I'm going to delete my previous comments.

Comment: I like your second answer, but there is a lot to unpack in it, (at least for me). For the equivalence, you also have to pick a basepoint for $Y$, don't you. I guess, I can accept it but there are a lot of technical details associated with the construction.

Comment: In a slightly more detail, the equivalence $\mathrm{Cov}(X) \to G-\mathrm{Sets}$ sends a covering projection $p : Y \to X$ to the set $p^{-1}(x_0)$ with the following $G$ action. To define the action of $g \in G = \pi_1(X,x_0)$ on some point $y_0 \in p^{-1}(x_0)$, take a loop $\gamma$ representing $g$, and take the unique lift of $\gamma$ starting at $y_0$, then the endpoint of the lift is what you define $g \cdot y_0$ to be (and you do this for every $y_0 \in p^{-1}(x_0)$). Is that what you meant, @Jeff?

Comment: It might be difficult to hash this all out in comments =).  I probably will ask a followup question to clarify. But the way I understand it, the action you described of an element of the fundamental group, takes a $y_0$ to another point in $p^{-1}(x_0)$, i.e. a deck transformation.

Comment: The above describes all the isomorphisms because in order to preserve $pf = p$ points in a fiber must be mapped to another point to a fiber. And secondarily, $f$ is unique given the value at point $f(y_0)$.